# GLSL - struct default constructor

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a GLSL vertex shader that uses arrays of structs for uniform variables

```
struct MyStruct
{
    lowp float var1;
    lowp float var2;
};

uniform MyStruct theUniform[16];
```

Is there a convenient way to initialize all var1,var2 in all array entries from inside the shader without defining everything explicitly? In C++ one would define a default constructor on MyStruct but I don't know if GLSL has something like this.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows better, but I'd say you're stuck with two options: Initialize the structs with a loop in GLSL, or upload the default data to that uniform before running the shader.

Comment: Since this is a uniform, you might as well initialize it on the CPU side, especially since uniforms are read-only on some platforms (such as OpenGL ES).